# Error al agregar ForeignKey en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table LUGAR_PERSONA
(
  lugar_id    NUMBER(8) not null,
  personal_id NUMBER(8) not null
)
nologging;
alter table LUGAR_PERSONA
  add constraint FK_lugar FOREIGN KEY (lugar_id) REFERENCES lugar(lugar_id);
  add constraint FK_personal FOREIGN KEY (personal_id) REFERENCES personal(personal_id);
```

Creo una tabla `LUGAR_PERSONA,` que debe ser una tabla intermedia para asociar uno o varios lugares a una o varias personas. Obviamente tengo creada la tabla personal y la tabla lugar.

Al intentar añadir las `FOREIGN KEY` me da este error.

> alter table LUGAR_PERSONA
>               * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

¿A qué se puede deber este error?

PD: Agrego la estructura de la tablas padre y lo hago como imagen porque es solo para mostrar osea esa parte se que está bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y sacando el nologging; antes del alter table? O bien hacerlo en dos consultas separadas.

Comment: Si lo quito me da unknown command beginning "add constr..." - rest of line ignored.

Comment: y aunque sea una sola igual me da error
ERROR at line 6: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 problemitas.  El primero, es que tienes un punto y coma de sobra al final de esta línea:

```
add constraint FK_lugar FOREIGN KEY (lugar_id) REFERENCES lugar(lugar_id);
```

La sentencia completa debería ser:

```
alter table LUGAR_PERSONA
  add constraint FK_lugar FOREIGN KEY (lugar_id) REFERENCES lugar(lugar_id) -- sin punto y coma aquí
  add constraint FK_personal FOREIGN KEY (personal_id) REFERENCES personal(personal_id);
```

Pero ese no es la causa de tu error. Pero lo menciono, porque una vez que resuelvas tu error actual, entonces recibirás otro diferente por causa del punto y coma.

El error que recibes se debe a que Oracle no es capaz de adquirir un lock para una de las tablas envueltas en el `alter table`. En este caso, lo más probable es que el problema sea con la tabla `lugar`.

Si verificas, seguramente encontrarás que alguien (tal vez tu mismo en una ventana diferente) tiene una transacción abierta con modificaciones a la tabla `lugar`. Y hasta que no se le haga un `commit` o `rollback` a esa transacción, el `alter table` seguirá dando ese error.

Comment: le quite el ; y me da éste error: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: Eso indicaría que `personal_id` no es la llave primaria de la tabla `personal`, lo que no creo que sea intencional. ¿Puedes verificar eso?

Comment: O tal vez es `lugar_id` que no es la llave primaria de la tabla `lugar`. Uno de los 2.

Comment: Definitivamente es es "eso indicaría que personal_id no es la llave primaria de la tabla personal, lo que no creo que sea intencional. ¿Puedes verificar eso?"... porque?? ni idea pero ya estoy orientado asi que muchas gracias a todos lo que aportaron

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

CONSTRAINT fk_column
    FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
);

Deja todo dentro del paréntesis del create table. De paso veo que falta ; en sentencia create.

Comment: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Comment: Eso me dice en cambio en la tabla principal tengo definida mi pk

Comment: Fijate en las tablas padre que las columnas esten definidas como PK:

Comment: add constraint PK_ID primary key (PERSONAL_ID);

Comment: con eso agregue en la tabla padre

Comment: Fijate en las tablas padre que las columnas estén definidas como PK:

`CREATE TABLE lugar
(
lugar_id NUMBER(8) not null,
...
CONTRAINT pk_lugar PRIMARY KEY (lugar_id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE persona
(
persona_id NUMBER(8) not null,
...
CONTRAINT pk_persona PRIMARY KEY (persona_id)
);`

Y luego:

`CREATE TABLE lugar_persona
(
lugar_id NUMBER(8) not null,
persona_id NUMBER(8) not null,
CONTRAINT fk_lugar FOREIGN KEY (lugar_id) REFERENCES lugar (lugar_id)
CONTRAINT fk_persona FOREIGN KEY (persona_id) REFERENCES persona (persona_id)
);`

Comment: Ahora edite mi pregunta y agregue una imagen con la estructura de las tablas padres y están tal cual me lo dices

Comment: Yo sigo pensando que hay un error de sintaxis, fijate aca:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp. Sobre todo cuando agregas el alter table

Comment: w3schools no es una buena referencia para determinar lo que es o no es válido en en el SQL de Oracle.